# Segmentation Fault in algorithm to separate strings

Tags: c, string, algorithm, gcc, split

I'm learning C by myself and I'm trying to use my knowledge (i.e. no library use) to create a program that does the following:

- Split a string into words (words are separated by spaces)
- Put each word in an array

So, in the end, I must have an array of strings (an array of array of chars).

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
int i, conta, indice_completo=0, indice_nome=0, indice_caractere=0;
char nome [90], nomevetor [30] [90];


scanf ("%[^\n]s", nome);

while (nome[indice_completo] != '\0') {
    while (nome[indice_completo] != ' ' && nome [indice_completo] != '\0') {
        nomevetor [indice_nome] [indice_caractere] = nome [indice_completo];
        indice_completo++;
        indice_caractere++;
    }
    nomevetor [indice_nome] [indice_caractere] = '\0';
    indice_caractere=0;
    indice_nome++;
}
conta=indice_nome;

for (i=0 ; i<conta; i++) {
    printf ("Nome %d: %s\n", i+1, nomevetor [i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

But when I compile it using:

```
gcc -ansi -Wall -g programa.c -o programa
```

I get segmentation fault.

- Why did I get segmentation fault?
- Is my algorithm correct?
- Is there a better way to do what I want?

Comment: I've corrected your English a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coding problem is that when you reach a blank in the input, you don't ever get past it.

Add a loop:

```
while (nome[indice_completo] == ' ')
    indice_completo++;
```

just before the end of the main loop.

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, conta, indice_completo = 0, indice_nome = 0, indice_caractere = 0;
    char nome[90], nomevetor[30][90];


    scanf("%[^\n]s", nome);

    while (nome[indice_completo] != '\0')
    {
        while (nome[indice_completo] != ' ' && nome[indice_completo] != '\0')
        {
            nomevetor[indice_nome][indice_caractere] = nome[indice_completo];
            indice_completo++;
            indice_caractere++;
        }
        nomevetor[indice_nome][indice_caractere] = '\0';
        printf("Word: <<%s>>\n", nomevetor[indice_nome]);
        indice_caractere = 0;
        indice_nome++;
        while (nome[indice_completo] == ' ')
            indice_completo++;
    }
    conta = indice_nome;

    for (i = 0; i < conta; i++)
    {
        printf("Nome %d: %s\n", i+1, nomevetor[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example run:

```
$ ./segfault
Arterial blockage I believe
Word: <<Arterial>>
Word: <<blockage>>
Word: <<I>>
Word: <<believe>>
Nome 1: Arterial
Nome 2: blockage
Nome 3: I
Nome 4: believe
$
```

(Only the program is now misnamed — it doesn't seg fault any more.)

You need to make sure nothing overflows the limits, too.  Mainly, that would be using `%89[^\n]` in the format string, since you can't have more than 45 alternating non-blank and blank in a 90-character buffer.

If the input starts with a blank, the first 'word' will be empty.  You could fix that by putting the 'skip' loop at the top of the main loop.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good overall, but when you detect a space, you still need to increment `indice_completo` otherwise you'll never get past it.

And then, you'l keep on incrementing `indice_nome` until you fall off the end of the array, hence the seg fault.